# Grouping by 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that shows how many messages, is being sent through my system the last year, grouped by months. Works perfectly!

The result look like this:

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Year | Month | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      2 |      3 |
| 2013 |    11 |      4 |     21 |     56 |
| 2013 |    12 |      1 |     10 |     16 |
| 2014 |     1 |      2 |     10 |     52 |
| 2014 |     2 |      1 |     62 |    118 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

*(type 1,2 and 3 is simply different types of USERS -ignore this)*

However, I'd like to avoid that the same receiver (msg_receiver) can be shown twice in the result set, for each month.

So if user 44 and 39 sends a message to user 70 in december, user_id 70 would only be counted ONCE for december. Currently, he will show up twice.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT
    Year(m.msg_date) as year,
    Month(m.msg_date) as month,
    sum(u.type = '1') as type_1,
    Sum(u.type = '2') as type_2,
    sum(u.type = '7') as type_3
FROM
    messages m
INNER JOIN
    users u ON u.user_id = m.msg_sender
WHERE
    m.msg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND month(msg_date) != month(curdate())
GROUP BY
    Month(m.msg_date) -- , m.msg_receiver (this does not work, it will no longer group by each month/year).
ORDER BY
    msg_date
```

The logical answer to this, would in my option be, to first group by month, then user_id (or vice via). But if I do this, the results looks strange. See:

**Using `GROUP BY Month(m.msg_date), u.user_id`**

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Year | Month | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    10 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      0 |     19 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013 |    11 |      2 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013 |    11 |      0 |      0 |     11 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

It does not group by months anymore, as it should.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify what exactly I want to achieve, as people have been a bit confused. Imagine this scenario:

```
It is December 2013.

USER 1 has written 5 messages to USER 2 (this should count as 1 in december)
USER 4 has written 1 message to USER 4 (this should count as 1 in december)
USER 3 has written 2 messages to USER 4 and 2 (this should count as 2 in december).

The totals of the month would then be 4. Because there has been 4 conversations.
```

Does it makes sense? I find my self often struggling with how to express my self correctly and understandable.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: in order to answer this - a question - if a receiver sends more than one message, and each message is a different type, which type do you want to count the receiver in?

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion. I have edited my answer to explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT` to only count each `msg_receiver` once per type:

```
SELECT
    Year(m.msg_date) as year,
    Month(m.msg_date) as month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '1' THEN m.msg_receiver END) as type_1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '2' THEN m.msg_receiver END) as type_2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '3' THEN m.msg_receiver END) as type_3
FROM
    messages m
INNER JOIN
    users u ON u.user_id = m.msg_sender
WHERE
    m.msg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND month(msg_date) != month(curdate())
GROUP BY
    Year(m.msg_date), Month(m.msg_date)
ORDER BY
    msg_date
```

*N.B I have added `Year(m.msg_date)` to your group by to ensure the results are determinate*

If the same user receives a message from two different users that have two different types, they will be counted in both types though. If this is not the intended result you would need to come up with some logic as to which type they should be counted in (Min, Max, Mode, Median etc)

If, for example, you wanted the minimum user type, you could use:

```
SELECT 
    m.year, 
    m.month, 
    sum(m.type = '1') as type_1,
    Sum(m.type = '2') as type_2,
    sum(m.type = '7') as type_3
FROM (  
        SELECT
            Year(m.msg_date) as year,
            Month(m.msg_date) as month,
             m.msg_receiver,
             MIN(u.type) AS type
        FROM 
            messages m
        INNER JOIN
            users u ON u.user_id = m.msg_sender
        WHERE
            m.msg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
            AND month(msg_date) != month(curdate())
        GROUP BY
            Year(m.msg_date), Month(m.msg_date), m.msg_receiver
    ) m
GROUP BY 
    m.Year, m.Month
ORDER BY
    m.year, m.month;
```

**EDIT**

In response to your updated question, in its current form my first answer would count your example as only 3 conversations not 4, as there were only 3 unique recipients. What you really need is to be able to count distinct over sender and receiver, i.e. `count(distinct m.msg_sender, m.msg_sender)`. Unfortunately this is not valid syntax, however, you can achieve essentially the same thing by concatenating the two fields (as long as they are separated by a character/characters that cannot appear in either. e.g

```
SELECT
    Year(m.msg_date) as year,
    Month(m.msg_date) as month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '1' THEN CONCAT(m.msg_sender, '|', m.msg_receiver) END) as type_1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '2' THEN CONCAT(m.msg_sender, '|', m.msg_receiver) END) as type_2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.type = '3' THEN CONCAT(m.msg_sender, '|', m.msg_receiver) END) as type_3
FROM
    messages m
INNER JOIN
    users u ON u.user_id = m.msg_sender
WHERE
    m.msg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND month(msg_date) != month(curdate())
GROUP BY
    Year(m.msg_date), Month(m.msg_date)
ORDER BY
    msg_date
```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I want to achieve. I will play around with it for a while, and see if it works. Great answer. Also, I have updated my answer to explain what I exactly want to count.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't posted a data structure, but it appears that you want to change the INNER JOIN to

```
INNER JOIN
    users u ON u.user_id = m.msg_receiver
```